# Mock server in Postman

Tags: rest, mocking, postman

I am wondering if it is possible to create a mock server in Postman which can be reached from a different device in the same network.
I would like to achieve the following:

- I have a device which is able to send push notifications - URL of the endpoint can be configured in the device
- I would like to create a mock server in Postman which runs on my PC and can capture the message and reply with specific code such as 200 OK

For example:
The device has URL endpoint configured with address:

```
https://<IP address of my PC>/endpoint
```

Is Postman app able to capture and process such requests?

So far I have found manuals where the Postman gives you URL link but it does not contain the IP address of the PC where the Postman is running and there is some ID instead.

I have tried to read several manuals and FAQs but I was not able to find any hint how to achieve what I have described.